# ANDROID.How to make voice input to text without google pop up appearing?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Hello android developers,

I'm beginners in android development. Got stuck with this problem -

I want to make voice to text input, but I don't want google popup appear. I've seen multiple apps that has voice inputs without that, so please maybe someone can help me figure it out?

Here the screenshot of popup[image]

Here is my code of MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView resultTV;

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    resultTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTV);
}


public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.imageButton) {

        promtSpeechInput();

    }


}

public void promtSpeechInput() {

    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
      i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
      i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
      i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "SAY SOMETHING");
      i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);



    try {

        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Say something kiddo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry, your device not support speech inputs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i){


        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code)
        {

            case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                resultTV.setText(result.get(0));

            }
            break;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this activity i created where when toggle button is switched on recording starts and the fluctuations in pitch of the voice is shown in a progressbar using the RmsChanged()  method, the text recognized is shown in a textview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener
{
private TextView returnedText;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
private Intent recognizerIntent;
private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    Button recordbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);


    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                              "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                              this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                              RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);

    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });






}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(10);
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
ArrayList<String> matches = arg0
        .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";

    returnedText.setText(text);


}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);

}

public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}




  }
```

**DO NOT FORGET ADDING THIS PERMISSION IN YOUR MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. It still not working, can you please share you android manifest permissions? :)

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. Bro i have just edited and added the required permission in the answer now,,,,you can check it out

Comment: you're awesome. Thanks you so much. One last thing. It gives me multiple output, how can I get just one output, what should I edit and play with ?  :)

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. Bro updated the answer have a look,,,what i did was removed the block of code that was setting text in onResults method and add it to onPartialResults method....this also gives you real time updating of the text as you speak...let me know if it worked

Comment: @ user5894647, thanks for patience. It worked! Just update one more time method OnPartialResults, something were wrong with arg0 and results arguments. Thank you so much man, I hope someone will help you the way you helped me, thanks!

Comment: it also crashes sometimes, it sounds like recording but text not changing, is there is something we can do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    SpeechRecognizer recognize=SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    recognize.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            String output = bundle.getString(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });
 recognize.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I put this code?

Comment: Write it inside promtSpeechInput() method